# Converting jsl script file

Tags: sas, sas-jmp

Please correct me if I'm wrong beginner user here from SAS. Currently I have a working script from jmp(.jsl) and it's logic is more on query related and I am just wondering if there is a possibility or features for sas that can import the jmp, because right now I am transferring it line by line and there are some functionalities that is supported in jmp and not working in sas.

I just simply need to migrate my script from jmp into sas. Any suggestions/comments TIA

Comment: There are no automatic translations that I'm aware of but if you post more specific details about the issues you're having you can get some help. JMP has a community forum, as does SAS that has the SAS developers if you really get stuck.